# Taking input from stdin segmentation fault

Tags: c, input, segmentation-fault, stdin

An expected input for the code I'm trying to run looks something like this:

(i,j) where i and j are integers. (Ex. (1,2), (10,21), etc).

I need to store the both integers in int variables.

This is what I did:

```
    getchar(); // gets open parenthesis

    // gets first num
    char *first;
    int z = 0;
    int a;

    while((a = getchar()) != ',') {
        first[z] = a;
        z++;
    }
    int firstNum;
    sscanf(first, "%d", &firstNum);
    printf("%d\n", firstNum); //checking if got correct num

    // gets second num
    char *second;
    int y = 0;
    int b;
    while((b = getchar()) != ')') {
        second[y] = b;
        y++;
    }
    int secondNum;
    sscanf(second, "%d", &secondNum);
    printf("%d\n", secondNum); //checking if got correct num
```

It works to get the first number. But, when I did it for the second number, I got a segmentation fault and I can't figure out why? I basically just redid the process of getting the first number?

Thanks!

Comment: `first` is only a pointer, it doesn't have any memory => use of malloc or raw array

Comment: I changed it to an array of size 100 and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Also, the newline that is written to stdin when you hit the enter key may cause problems with subsequent calls to `sscanf`.  Include a space in the first part of your format string to consume the `\n`: `sscanf(first," %d", &firstNum);`

Comment: Also, because I can guess you're a beginner, best tool than log (ie printf) to see if a software works well and if not finding where is the bug, is the debugger. Debugger is design to find bug. BUT, it is also a really good tools to learn, specially c: you can run step by step your soft and see what's happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first and second should be arrays and not pointers.
Both of your pointers point to some place in the memory, and when accessing them "as arrays" you override different memory.

change:

```
char *first;
char *second;
```

To be:

```
char first[128] ={0};
char second[128] ={0};
```

As well, read the following:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-pointer-array-c/
It explains about the difference between array and pointer in a very clear way.